# Next JS app crushes on IE when using multiple configuration plugins

Tags: internet-explorer, next.js, material-ui, i18next

I have a small project built with Next JS and MUI. Production build works perfectly fine on Chrome and Firefox, but I had some problems with running it on IE and Safari.

Turned out it was the MUI package that caused the problem. So I was able to fix it by using "next-transpile-modules" like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@mui/base',
  '@mui/material',
  '@mui/styles',
  '@mui/system',
  '@mui/styled-engine',
  '@mui/utils',
  '@mui/private-theming',
]);

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost', 'lh3.googleusercontent.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = nextTranslate(withTM(nextConfig));
```

This configuration works for Safari, but not for IE. Here's why: **if I use only withTM() then it will work for IE too**, but then I will lose my translations. So I guess it's the combination of plugins that creates the issue.

IE console prints this message (with config.optimization.minimize = false;):

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you've blurred the error message?

Comment: It's in cyrillic. So I decided to blur it since it wouldn't be helpful for the majority of people. It was just a standard error message, nothing particularly interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved this problem with the help of '@webcomponents/shadydom' and 'intl-pluralrules'.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sorry, can't mark my own message as an answer after 14 hours.